# KendoGrid to Tab Delimated File Directly into a Folder

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to generate a tab delimated file from my kendo grid table and download/place that file into a certain file location using javascript/jquery.

I have created my table and pulling the data in from Cosmosdb with an api, however I am not sure of the best way to go about getting the data into the tab delimated format and directly place it into the folder location.

If there is a easier way through Azure, I would greatly appreciate any help I could get on this issue.

I have my fields

```
function loadPersonGrid(){
    $("#personGrid").kendoGrid({
        
    columnMenu:{
        filterable: true,
        sortable: true,
    },
    sortable: true,
    filterable: true,
    toolbar:["create","excel", "Send Report"],
    excel: {
        fileName: "example.xlsx",
        filterable: true
    },
    
    noRecords:{
        template: "<div style='margin:1.5%;min-height:100px;'><b>&quot;No data available. Please try again later.&quot</b></div>",
    },
    columns:[
        {
            field:"id",
            title:"id",
            
        },
        {
            field:"Age",
            title:"Age",
        },
        {
            field:"Name",
            title:"Name",
        },
        {
            field:"Number",
            title:"Number",
        },
    ],
    editable: true,
});
```

and I need to create the file along the lines of

```
id    Age    Name    Number
#    #    #    #
#    #    #    #
```

into a .txt file directly into the folder path C:\Users\exampleuser\Documents...

Comment: I don't really see this as a Cosmos DB question, unless there's something specific you're having an issue with, query-wise?